# R logistic regression

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

I am very new to statistics and **R**. In my dataset the target variable is flight status to predict if the flight could be delayed or it could be on-time. So, it has two values for response variable - Delayed and on-time. So, in order to construct a logistic regression model using **R**, do we have to recode the target variable to 0 and 1 first? I mean does it need to be 0-Delayed and 1 for Ontime. or can I keep the target variable as factor?

Please forgive me for the basic question.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

In one of the solutions for the projects, I saw it was converted to the numeric before proceeding further? But is there any recommended way or what do you think most of the people would follow as a standard? I am just getting to learn R and statistics and I am interested in the best practices.

Comment: Bottom line, no need to recode as long as your variables are of the correct class (e.g. `factor`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data(iris)

Binary dependent variable:
iris$Species_binary <- ifelse(iris$Species=="setosa", "no", "yes")
```

Does it work as a factor?

```
glm(as.factor(iris$Species_binary)~iris$Sepal.Length, family="binomial")
```

Yes, it does.

> ```
> Call:  glm(formula = as.factor(iris$Species_binary) ~ iris$Sepal.Length, 
>     family = "binomial")
>
> Coefficients:
>       (Intercept)  iris$Sepal.Length  
>           -27.829              5.176  
>
> Degrees of Freedom: 149 Total (i.e. Null);  148 Residual
> Null Deviance:        191 
> Residual Deviance: 71.84  AIC: 75.84
> ```

Would it work as a logical (boolean) variable?

```
glm(I(iris$Species_binary=="yes")~iris$Sepal.Length, family="binomial")
```

> ```
> Call:  glm(formula = I(iris$Species_binary == "yes") ~ iris$Sepal.Length, 
>     family = "binomial")
>
> Coefficients:
>       (Intercept)  iris$Sepal.Length  
>           -27.829              5.176  
>
> Degrees of Freedom: 149 Total (i.e. Null);  148 Residual
> Null Deviance:        191 
> Residual Deviance: 71.84  AIC: 75.84
> ```

Yes, it would. Of course, a numeric variable would also work.

This is the case in most other packages/functions for logit as well, but it's possible that some could behave differently. Note that the logistic link is the default for the binomial family, which is why I didn't have to specify it.

Be sure that you know which level of the factor is counted as the positive level if you do it that way, though! Otherwise your interpretation of the results will be backwards.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

In one of the solutions for the projects, I saw it was converted to the numeric before proceeding further? But is there any recommended way or what do you think most of the people would follow as a standard? I am just getting to learn R and statistics and I am interested in the best practices.

Comment: @lak3567bo You're welcome. Most people would convert it to numeric so that they can know with certainty that the factor level intended to be the positive level is being treated as such. Since the option exists to do it other ways there's no universal standard practice, but within contexts where there is a standard (like your course, or certain journals, etc) the standard would likely be to convert it to numeric first. If you'd like you can click the little check mark my by answer to let future readers know that this was the answer. :)

Comment: Formula interface usage could be better. I understand this may be for demonstration purposes but no need to teach beginners something that will bite them down the line. `mdl <- glm(as.factor(iris$Species_binary)~iris$Sepal.Length, family="binomial");
predict(mdl, newdata = iris[1:5, ]); iris$Species_binary <- as.factor(iris$Species_binary);
mdl2 <- glm(Species_binary ~ Sepal.Length, family = binomial, data = iris);
predict(mdl2, newdata = iris[1:5, ])`